# DITA-OT not supporting legitimate local XREF references

Tags: dita, oxygenxml, dita-ot

I'm creating an XREF to an anchor on the same page.  I'm following the DITA standard practice of formatting it as `#[topic]/[id]`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE reference
  PUBLIC '-//OASIS//DTD DITA Reference//EN'
  'reference.dtd'>
<reference id="dummy-page">
    <title> Dummy page title</title>
    <refbody>
        <section>
            <title>Section One</title>
            <xref format="" href="#dummy-page/target">
                <b>DITA-formatted link</b>
            </xref>
        </section>
        <section id="target">
            <title>Section Two</title>
            <div>Lower content</div>
        </section>
    </refbody>
</reference>
```

But, in the generated HTML (XHTML Transform in Oxygen-XML, or DITA-OT publish command) the two ids (xref and element-id) don't match, so the link does not work:
[image: generated-html]

Any clues to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aah, have got it.  The `format=""` in the XREF was preventing `DITA-OT` from mangling the anchor to match the one used in the published HTML.

Providing `format="dita"` or removing the `format` attribute altogether generates valid code.

Comment: You should mark this answer as accepted answer.

Comment: I tried to. SO is making me wait 2 days before I can mark it as accepted.